# Forward sent mails on port 25 to port 465 with firewall

Tags: email, ssl, exchange

Our customer can not send emails to another company. The error says that the mail has been rejected because it is sending mails over an unsecured connection (**port 25**). So if the Exchange 2013 Server would send the mails over a secured connection (**port 465**) the mailserver on the other side would accept the mails.
So my question is, if I would configure a DNAT on the Sophos firewall that would route all inside traffic from port 25 to port 465, may it be possible that the other companys server would accept the mail? 
Or do I have to reconfigure the Exchange server to send mails over a secured connection?

Many thanks in advance
Kind regards

Comment: And the Sophos firewall should then handle the encrypted email transfer rather the MS Exchange Server? I mean changing the port didn´t mean that the email transfer is encrypted (you need at least a propper SSL certificate).

Comment: No. On port 465 is there ssl communication.

Answer (score 3):

> the mail has been rejected because it is sending mails over an unsecured connection (port 25)). So if the Exchange 2013 Server would send the mails over a secured connection <strike>(port 465)</strike> the mailserver on the other side would accept the mails.

If the remote mailserver is configured correctly it supports [STARTTLS/Opportunistic TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS), which allows using the same port, TCP port 25 in the case of SMTP, for use without and with TLS.

Outlook 2013 is by default configured to also use [Opportunistic TLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430753(v=exchg.150).aspx) and should attempt TLS for all remote connections (over port 25).

So if the lack of encryption is an issue, either the default settings with regard to opportunistic TLS on the exchange server have been modified, or that remote server is configured incorrectly.

Neither will be resolved by a DNAT rule in your firewall, so please don't attempt that.

Port 465 with an TLS only SMTP server is [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS). (It might still be offered to support some older  e-mail clients but isn't used for mail delivery between SMTP servers over the internet, those would always default to using port 25.)